# C# File Move Often Very Slow

Tags: c#, file, move

I have a Windows Forms application that I run  without showing a form as a command line application. I attach a console in order to write to stdout. In this mode a file move (File.Move) of a 100 Kbyte file between two local filesystem locations often takes 90 seconds, but sometimes is very fast. The file move changes the file name and extension in the same directory. The initial file extension is .jpg and the destination file extension is .tmp. If I attach the Visual Studio IDE to the running command line  executable and set a breakpoint before the File Move it executes very quickly.

If run the program from the Visual Studio IDE (using parameters to stop any form from being shown) and set the breakpoint before the File Move, it executes very quickly.  If I set the breakpoint after the File Move the program often takes 90 seconds to reach the breakpoint. It appears that stopping the program before the File Move allows it to execute quickly.

Using OpenedFilesView to inspect open files during the 90 second wait I can see the file being renamed as opened by System Process. I check for the source file (NewFile) being locked before the move. It is written earlier in the program using the following code:

```cs
Image Img = new Bitmap(sFile);
PropertyItem[] propItems = Img.PropertyItems;
string NewFile = sFile + "_1.jpg";
// For each PropertyItem in the array, display the id, 
// type, and length.
Encoding _Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
PropertyItem propItem2 = Img.PropertyItems[0];
Image file;
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    file = Image.FromStream(stream);
    if (sTagName == "XPTitle") propItem2.Id = 0x9c9b;  // this is called 'XPTitle'
    if (sTagName == "XPComment") propItem2.Id = 0x9c9c;  // this is called 'XPComment'
    propItem2.Type = 2;
    propItem2.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sTagValue + "\0");
    propItem2.Len = propItem2.Value.Length;
    file.SetPropertyItem(propItem2);
    file.Save(NewFile);
    file.Dispose();
    file = null;
    stream.Dispose();
}
Img.Dispose();
Img = null;
System.IO.File.Delete(sFile);
System.IO.File.Move(NewFile, sFile); // sometimes hangs here
```

The File is not locked before the move. Locking is checked by trying to open a filestream from the source file path using Read/Write access.

Building and running the application as a console application does not change the behaviour.

Putting in a Thread.Sleep(1000) before the File Move makes it run very quickly but I would like to know why this is effective.

I am running in a Windows 10 environment, with MalwareBytes Antivirus software

Comment: Delays that long are invariably the handiwork of anti-malware.  They get their underwear in a bundle first from an EXE file that seemingly appears from nowhere.  If that program then starts dropping files then it gets to be extra suspicious.  Perhaps switching to their "deep scan" algorithm.  The kind of bogus feature that makes it sound good but covers up the fact that their scan engine is too lame to do it quickly.  There is only a subset of anti-malware products that are suitable for use on a dev machine.  The only that's included with the OS will not hassle you and does the job just fine.

Comment: It turns out the MalwareBytes AV is not running so the delay isn't due to anti-malware.

Comment: Your code does not correspond to it's description in question. Could you elaborate a bit about what is intended code functionality?

Comment: The code is intended to add an EXIF tag (either XPTitle of XP Comment)  to a JPEG file. The opening, deleting and renaming is to overcome the fact that if a tag has to be added to a file, it has to be saved with a different name.

Comment: @SimonKravis not that this answers why it's taking so long but what gives you the impression that if you modify the file it has to be saved with a different name? You should reuse the same file and simply overwrite its content

Comment: @SimonKravis Also you're doing very odd things, like disposing of the stream while you're in a using block that handles that for you, setting file to null, and disposing of the file instead of using another using statement. I would remove the file declaration out of the block (you're not using it outside) putting it in a using(Image file = Image.FromStream(stream) and get rid of file.dispose / file = null / stream.dispose, you can also apply the same logic to img. This removes a lot of boilerplate code that is absolutely not needed